# Codeception and elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, codeception

I have a test-driven application which is built with Laravel and Codeception. Laravel application is also integrated with Elastic search. 
Are there any modules available in Codeception for integrating elastic search?

Answer (score 2):

Quick google search finds `codeception-elasticsearch` module.
Active fork is https://packagist.org/packages/tadaspaplauskas/codeception-elasticsearch

It has no documentation, so you have to look at  the source code: https://github.com/tadaspaplauskas/codeception-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/Elasticsearch.php

It provides expected methods:

- haveInElasticsearch
- seeInElasticsearch
- dontSeeInElasticsearch
- grabFromElasticsearch

I will leave it up to you to figure out how to configure it,
from the source code I can only see that it takes `hosts` and `cleanup` parameters,
so configuration would look like this:

```
modules:
  enabled:
     Elasticsearch:
       hosts: ''
       cleanup: true
```